# CSS: How to select only the first non-adjacent sibling after the element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML page like this:

```
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>

 <div></div>

 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>

 <div></div>
```

and this pattern continues.

Normally the div elements should not display so:

```
div{display:none;}
```

But when a paragraph is hovered, the first div element after that should be displayed:

```
p:hover+div{display:block;}
```

but this works only for the previous `p` . and this:

```
p:hover~div{display:block;}
```

shows all `div`s after the hovered `p` not just the first one after.

How could I display only the first non-adjacent div after the hovered `p`?

[here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ncm5uoz/)

Actually I am looking for a selector like `first-sibling`.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the query. Are you looking at a way to display only the first `div` following the `p` tags? I am not sure if my answer is confirming with your need.

Comment: @Harry Thanks , your answer is the solution :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the below setting:

```
p:hover ~ div ~ div {
    display:none;
}
```

This would set the display back to none for all `div` after the first `div` following the hovered paragraph.

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
p:hover ~ div {
  display: block;
}
p:hover ~ div ~ div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>
<div>d1</div>
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>
<div>d2</div>
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>
<div>d3</div>
```

Comment: Oops, didn't realize you had this answer but deleted it.

Comment: @BoltClock: No worries mate. It was my mistake to keep deleting/undeleting it due to (a) being unsure of the need and (b) system issues :(

Comment: This looks like the optimal answer based on the limited known HTML structure.

Comment: Very elegant indeed! +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using this:

```css
div {
  display: none;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
p:hover+div,
p:hover+p+div,
p:hover+p+p+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>

<div>Ipsum</div>

<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>

<div>Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Useful obviously if the actual structure is **only** 4 paragraphs and a div otherwise it's very inflexible.

Comment: But the OP said this will follow that structure?

Comment: Actually he said "like" this...not that it was the precise structure. If there were 12 paragraphs and then a div  you'd have a lot of `+p` statements. I'm not saying your answer is wrong...just that it's limited.

Comment: I thought there is some selector like `first-sibling-after` . Is there anything like that?

Comment: @Aaron: You can't really blame him. Too often we answer questions only for the asker to change their markup later in a way that invalidates the answer because we made too many assumptions about the original markup.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "first-sibling" selector, but you can override the style for subsequent `div` elements using the same technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107):

```
div, 
p:hover ~ div ~ div {
    display: none;
}

p:hover ~ div {
    display: block;
}
```

This is preferred if you do not know the maximum number of `p` elements that can separate `div` elements in advance, or you would rather not have to hardcode all the adjacent selectors necessary as shown in Aaron's answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Actually, by the time being, the number of paragraphs between `div`s are known, But who knows? maybe in the future the `HTML` change, so I prefer this general answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would place your blocks between section tags. Then `<p>` tags and `<div>` tag are siblings from the same element. Also if these tags belong to each other its also good to reflect this in your markup.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hnf2Lrtr/1/)

```
<section>
 <p>hello</p>
 <p>world</p>
 <p>bar</p>

 <div></div>
</section>

<section>
 <p>hello</p>
 <p>world</p>
 <p>bar</p>

 <div></div>
</section>
```

css

```
section p:hover~div{display:block;}
```